# Magento 2 FEDEX/DHL/USPS/UPS Exception. "This shipping method is currently unavailable."

Tags: magento2, shipping, fedex, usps, dhl

I tried it through a custom shipping module and its readily showing up but Fedex/DHL/USPS/UPS are throwing exceptions on Checkout page..

Exception : **"This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."**

[image]

Help is really appreciated :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this from a different network. The issue might be that the web services url are blocked in your office network. This prevents the request from hitting the shipping carrier servers. Also recheck your credentials before entering.

Trying from a different network connection worked for me !

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I switched my IP and network..Worked butter smooth...much appreciated!..

Comment: I am facing the same issue but in Magento 1.9 . I changed the I.p address but throwing same issue. Credentials are doubled check. Any other solution. Thank You

Comment: @Saurabh : Try assigning some weight to the product and set maximum weight allowed (more than product's weight) in the shipping methods config..

Comment: @Saurabh - Also make sure that the weight that you enter for the product is lower than maximum weight accepted by the carrier(eg FedEx.)

Comment: Thank You KartikKakde and  @PiyushDangre. Weight setting is perfect.  When I changed Shipping origin to the USA its work perfectly but my client registered as it as India origin. When I set origin as India it gave me an error in the log and in frontend no shipping is available. Can you suggest what to do. FedEx supports are not responding properly

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan : Check whether your soap services are enabled or not? Uncomment "extension=php_soap.dll" in "php.ini" in Apache server and restart..

Comment: @Kartik I it is uncommented.

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan What is the Error in the log ?